# Multiplying an amount by 0.45 up until 833 then the remain by 0.25

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Fairly new to excel and its not something i would usually go into too much detail with, i used simple formula to get what little i need to do on it.

However, recently i have found myself using it abit more. I currently use excel to monitor and track my mileage for work as it requires me to travel as im a field engineer.

I have a sheet for each month which im using and then its all linked back to a quick summary page.

On this summary page i have the amount of miles ive currently remaining to hand in (hand in mid way each month).

What i want to be able to do is calculate how much i will be getting back.

The calculation is pretty straight forward however i dont know how to make it work in excel.

I need to be able to be able to multiply the amount by 0.45 up until 833. Then anything remaining after 833 gets multiplied by 0.25.

Example would be 1000 miles.

```
1000-833 = 167
833 * 0.45 = 375.85
167 * 0.25 = 41.75
375.85 + 41.75 = 417.60
```

Now this might be easy in that i could just subtract 833 from the amount and then multiple the remainer by 0.25 and add it like i did above. However the problem is, what if i dont do 833 miles that month. say i do 600?

Not really sure how to even approach this. If anyone could give me a hand, even if not the formula a way to approach this? im really new to excel so i dont know if you can use if statements as if i could i could just say if the amount is above 833 minus 833 from it else * 0.45. I just dont know if excel allows me to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The formula should be:

`=MAX(A1-833,0)*0.25 + MIN(833,A1)*0.45`

Basically, subtract 833 from A1. If it's greater than zero, multiply that difference by 0.25.

Then, if A1 is less than 833, multiply A1 by 0.45 If it's greater than 833, multiply 833 by 0.45.

Comment: this is perfect. tested it and it works a treat. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

With a value in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=IF(A1<=833,A1*0.45,375.85+0.25*(A1-833))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess the below formula will also help you if you track Miles that you travelled by Day.

**=IF((SUM(B:B)>833),(((SUM(B:B)-833)*0.25)+(833*0.45)),(SUM(B:B)*0.45))**

In this case, just B:B is the entire column of Miles you are tracking by day.

Thanks!